# TypeError: createButtonCollector is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

I'm trying to send an embed with buttons but when I try to add a collector using `createButtonCollector`, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: press.createButtonCollector is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix+ 'test')) {
    let first = new disbut.MessageButton().setStyle("blurple").setID("1").setLabel("Confirm") //first button
    let second = new disbut.MessageButton().setStyle("red").setID("2").setLabel("Cancel") //second button
    var buttons = [first, second]
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
      .setTitle(":fire: Test")
      .setDescription("Yes")
      .setColor("#BEBDBD")
      .setTimestamp("Today"+ message.createdAt)
    let press = message.channel.send({ embed: embed, buttons: buttons })

    const collector = press.createButtonCollector((button)=> button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id, { time: 60e3 })

     collector.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
      console.log('run successfully')
      if (button.id === "1") {
        button.channel.send("it worked");
      } else if 
        (button.id == "2") {
        button.message.delete(0500);
      }
     })
    }
```

I don't know what else is wrong.

Comment: `press.createButtonCollector = function() {}` - now it's a function - but it won't do anything - what should it do?

Comment: I did
` press.createButtonCollector = function() {
    const collector = press.createButtonCollector((button)=> button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id, { time: 60e3 }) //switch this part out if you have to
//then the rest of your code`

but yeah, it still didnt register

Comment: Are you sure? it's not in the code you posted

Comment: I added in what you gave, which is the `press.createButtonCollector = function() {}` in my code, it worked, its a function now, but the button presses still wont register

Comment: @Jimboy What Bravo's commented meant to be a joke... Try to focus on my answer below :)

Comment: why would you do put the code you pass as a callback into the function definition wher eyou want to use it? that makes no sense ... where is the function defined in your actual code

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros wasn't a joke - it was defining a function - the code doesn't do that, so I thought OP may need to know how

Comment: Oh, I thought... Whatever. OP obviously didn't want it to be a function that way. The error says it's not a function because `.send()` returns a pending promise and until it's resolved, `press.createButtonCollector` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`press` seems to be a pending promise, as `message.channel.send()` [returns a promise](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). You'll need to wait for it to be resolved. Once it's resolved, `discord-buttons`' `createButtonCollector()` will be available to use.

```js
let press = await message.channel.send({ embed: embed, buttons: buttons })

// now the promise is resolved, createButtonCollector() is the function/method you want
let collector = press.createButtonCollector(
  (button) => button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id,
  { time: 60e3 }
)
```

Make sure, it's in a an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: if press is the pending promise, then your code makes no difference ... `(await press).createButtonCollector(....)` would await the `press` promise, but your code makes no difference

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've fixed the code above.